# How to increase reputation when unable to answer or comment

Tags: support

I answered a bunch of questions that were all related to Uploaded Content in production isn't visible in Communities. Apparently I triggered the ban hammer for posting the same snippet of code as an answer which deleted my posts. Now I'm unable to answer any questions which the Help Center says start by fixing my previous answers....well there's only ONE, and I can't comment due to reputation level is too low. So any suggestions or is my account just FUBAR'd?

I'm specifically trying to answer this question here: [Napili - Article content missing from Article Content Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198646/napili-article-content-missing-from-article-content-component) with my answer here:

"If you're trying to "hard code" a specific article such that it shows on the page you'll want to use the KnowledgeArticleVersionID and not the KnowledgeArticleId. We're using a specific article for announcements that is shown at the top of the home page. The easiest way that I've found to get to the KnowledgeArticleVersionId is enabling Lightning Experience, search for the article and click on the link. In the URL you'll see an Object Id that starts with "ka4" vs the KnowledgeArticleId starts with kA4 (capital 'A') grab this Id and paste into the Article Component. You'll need to repeat this process anytime you publish a new version of the article."

Comment: You actually have three answers, but two of them are deleted. That reflects negatively on your quality score.

Comment: I can see one deleted comment, here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54041/share-a-file-to-a-community-user-through-apex/151927#151927 however my answer was reposted at the top...not sure what to do, or how to go about increasing the quality score when I can't do anything other than suggest edits to posts.

Comment: It's your deleted `Answers` that drag down your quality score. You have a deleted `Answer` on the post you linked to in addition to your other answer, and another deleted `Answer` [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/151749/2995). Comments are a completely different mechanism than Answers.

Comment: Ah! Couldn't find that last one! Thanks for finding that, I've added additional info to that Answer and flagged it for review...hopefully this gets me back on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You had two out of your three `Answer` posts both deleted and down-voted. That's a pretty shallow hole to dig your way out of. In light of your improvements to one of the aforementioned posts, I undeleted it, and now your answer ban has been lifted.

The key is to maintain a positive contribution track record. That history includes deleted posts, flags, and so on. Remember, [don't be too overly self-promotional](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), which looks like it was a factor in getting you banned in the first place.

Comment: Understood and will do,  thanks for taking care of that.